# Which flow for securing a data-only microservice with Openid

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, keycloak

There are three parties in my application:

- A web client W (written in Angular)
- Microserice A ("my" microservice, developed in C++)
- Microservice B (developed by a 3rd party but using SSO, trusted microservice)

General communication between those three: The web client W could be either a frontend UI or a mobile device using just the API as a service without having any sort of frontend. W connects to microservice A to manipulate and consume data from it. Microservice A exchanges data with microservice B and vice versa. W does not need to know about B.

I've settled on an architecture for the web client using Openid Authorization Code Flow with PKCE enabled to get and refresh it's token from Keycloak. I've posted a related question here [1].

Now consider this Web Application W is consuming some data from my microservice A. The JWT token from the web client is sent to the microservice as Bearer Authorization.

So far so good. What kind of flow should I use for the microservice itself, in order to enable the service to fetch and eventually refresh tokens for its own use for verification and user info requests? I've read quite a lot, but at almost every place there is a client at play in the workflow.

Can the PKCE Auth Code flow be used for microservices (e.g. instead of logging in let the server send credentials in exchange for a short-lived token)? Or should the microservice simply fetch tokens via secret in confidential mode?

Since I'm implementing the microservice in C++ it basically means there is a lack of libraries. Thus would be good if you detail the flow, since I have to implement it.

[1] [OpenID redirect vs bearer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160447/openid-redirect-vs-bearer)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly there are a couple of auth patterns going on:

1. Web Application W -> Microservice A    (User Involved)
2. Microservice A -> Microservice B       (NO User Involved)
3. (Maybe) Web Application W -> Microservice A -> Microservice B  (User Involved)

   1. Any requests that come from the client (Web Application W) would use the Bearer Authorization which it sounds like you are currently doing.
   2. When doing server to server auth you can setup another client in Keycloak and set the "Access Type" to "Confidential" (like you mentioned) and then Microservice A can get a token and use that to communicate with Microservice B securely.
   3. If Web Application W is involved in a request to Microservice B (via Microservice A) you can just use the same bearer token that was on the header to Microservice A.